# eth.sendTransaction from eth.coinbase makes multiple transactions and decrease the eth.coinbase balance

Tags: go-ethereum

Im working on a distributed application using Ethereum, the go-ethereum implementation (Geth).

On a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 16.04) i have installed geth.

I have created a structure like this:

```
devnet$ tree -L 2
.
├── accounts.txt
├── boot.key
├── genesis.json
├── node1
│   ├── geth
│   ├── keystore
│   └── password.txt
```

I have:

- One bootnode/discovery node
- One Seal/full node

The seal node is initialized this way:

```
geth --datadir node1/ init genesis.json
```

Then the bootnode:

```
devnet$ bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr :30310
INFO [02-07|22:44:09] UDP listener up                          self=enode://3ec4fef2d726c2c01f16f0a0030f15dd5a81e274067af2b2157cafbf76aa79fa9c0be52c6664e80cc5b08162ede53279bd70ee10d024fe86613b0b09e1106c40@[::]:30310
```

And after the bootnode is listening, i run geth on the node1:

```
geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://3ec4fef2d726c2c01f16f0a0030f15dd5a81e274067af2b2157cafbf76aa79fa9c0be52c6664e80cc5b08162ede53279bd70ee10d024fe86613b0b09e1106c40@127.0.0.1:30310' --networkid 1515 --gasprice '1' -unlock '0x87366ef81db496edd0ea2055ca605e8686eec1e6' --password node1/password.txt --mine
```

Note: this are examples, the real ip, bootnode "enode" value and account arent those.

On this private ethereum network i have deployed a ERC20 contract, with a basic Transfer function, so, i wanted to invoke that function from Metamask, using some random address.

For that, i needed to get some ETH in my account, so i have connected to the geth console and transfer some ether from the eth.coinbase to that addres:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:"0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732", value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")})
```

After that, I discovered that some transactions that I had no way to identify,  i mean, it was only a transaction to send ether from one account to another, why that result in multiple transactions submitted?

Here is a screenshot of the situation:

[image]

Also, every one of those transactions is decreasing the eth.coinbase balance (eth.coinbase == the address that deploys the contract), so i started with a huge amount of Ether on that account and after some of those "ghost" transactions the balance of eth.coinbase was like 0.0026 Ether..

So, i have 2 questions

1. Is there any scenario that could decrease the contract owner address/coinbase balance?
2. Any ideas of why those transactions appear?

**EDIT**:

Caused by bots:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Ocean does not block any ports by default, to my knowledge.

In all probability, your node's RPC is publicly accessible, and when you unlock the account to send your transaction, a bot tries to sweep the rest to its own address (potentially more than one, since there seem to be multiple recipients).

Try blocking access to the RPC ports from outside the machine using ufw, or simply turn off RPC, since the console works over IPC.

Indeed, if you look at [0x6e4cc3e76765bdc711cc7b5cbfc5bbfe473b192e](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6e4cc3e76765bdc711cc7b5cbfc5bbfe473b192e) and [0x7097f41f1c1847d52407c629d0e0ae0fdd24fd58](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7097f41f1c1847d52407c629d0e0ae0fdd24fd58) on the mainnet, you can see that they have swept close to 15 ETH, and the pending transactions reflect a common tactic of such bots, which is to presign transactions of varying value with higher nonces while the rpc is unlocked.

Comment: Yes, D.O doesnt block the ports, but, if i want to access from outside the droplet via rpc or ws i cannot take that restriction, and thats a requirement for me. About the bot theory, which action is it doing? I mean, i dont know which operation can make the coinbase empty from the outside. Could you explain that more? its also curious that only when i execute the sendTransaction function this happen

Comment: Also, there are 2 recipients, and one of them is the contract address

Comment: See my edit, they are almost certainly bots, their mainnet accounts reflect the same

Comment: You can also use ufw to restrict RPC port access to just the IP you will use to call it.

Comment: Really interesting! So, i am allowing all the origins for rpc and websocket because i want my contract to be hitted from any address. How can i prevent this considering that precondition?

Comment: About restrict RPC port to a IP, the thing is that i want to allow rpc calls from any IP.. because its a private network that the contract must be accessed from any origin

Comment: In that case, either never unlock an account on the node, or set up another node with no keys on it, and use that for public access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80967/discussion-between-marcos-martinez-and-raghav-sood).

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16691 same problem, bots confirmed. The thing is.. how to expose your chain to the networwork without having this exploit?

Comment: You run a node with no unlocked keys, that's the only way if you wish to have a public rpc.

Comment: But if you run a node with no unlocked keys you cannot seal the blocks right? So if i hit that node how can the transaccion be process? Or there is a way to  that transaction be taked by another peer?

Comment: Run a second node that does not seal blocks and expose that as the public rpc node.

Comment: Do you refeer to a second node that isnt a Sealer node? a Standard node?

Comment: I have tried that but the transaction isnt broadcasted to the miner node, maybe is related with this: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2769

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. I would suggest opening an issue on Github for geth, and detailing your network setup. They can likely help you better than I can

Comment: Posted here, just if anybody faces the same problem: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17294